# Update sqlite column value only specefic part

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have sqlite database in which I have table "scripts" in that table I have columns, on of a column which name is "fname" have values like this

```
111/222/333
111/222
111/222/444/555
111/888/777
```

now I want to update all values whcih contains 222, so I want to run command and update values like following 222 to 000

```
111/000/333
111/000
111/000/444/555
111/888/777
```

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace the string occurrence ...

```
update whatever_table
set whatever_field = replace(whatever_field, '222', '000')
where (WHATEVER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy);
```

Execute a query to **find** the 222

```
Cursor c=query.("scripts","fname",null,null,"/222/",null);
```

Once you get the cursor object, you can loop through the Cursor which contains all rows that has "/222/".